# CSS - Creating a play button

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/0nvns9Lj/1/

I've done what I need to do but don't know if it's the best way - I'm sure it should be easier.

I just need to create a play button so I have a circle containing a triangle.

It's working but seems like alot of messing for something simple

```
        .wrap{
            background: #ddd;
            height: 300px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .circle{
            background: red;
            border-radius: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            width: 50px;
            margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
        }
        .circle_inner{
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .circle_inner:before{
            content: "";
            display: block;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px 0 10px 20px;
            border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ffffff;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin: -10px 0 0 -7px;
        }
```

Comment: why not just using a background image?

Comment: @imnancysun there are plenty of reasons. Why not give the OP the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Since the code you have written works fine I've voted to close. I believe optimization requests may be welcome here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ...however I don't think there is anything particularly complicated about your current code.

Comment: your question would be more on topic on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but you could try this http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ym2gxmq8/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your code works fine and should be posted on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to be reviewed and improved

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can (and should) do this simpler.

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0 }

figure {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 200px;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

figure button[name="play"] {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
figure button[name="play"]:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid hsl(210, 58%, 69%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px hsla(210, 76%, 57%, 0.5);
}

figure button[name="play"]::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <button name="play"></button>
</figure>
```

Editable demo: [http://jsbin.com/mipali/5](http://jsbin.com/mipali/5/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 2):

There is not much to improve.

Maybe you can use a special font like 'Webdings', and otherwise you can make a simple CSS triangle. In both cases you just need a simple element for the button, and a `::before` pseudo-element for the shape. In the HTML and CSS below, both methods are shown.

Both buttons use a normal `A` element, so the buttons could (if you can find any url or useful onclick event to attach to it) still work as a normal link when you don't even have CSS (think about the visually impaired).

Moreover, the HTML doesn't contain any extra markup apart from the class names. No 'inner' element needed, and I think that's the most important improvement. The CSS isn't that much shorter than your's but I got rid of the 'inner' element, so the markup is completely clean.

And remember: if you want more complex shapes, you also have a `::after` pseudo-element at your disposal. :)

```css
/* Basic red round button properties */
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  /* Hide the text 'play', which is present in the HTML document for accessibility */
  font-size: 0;
}

/* Properties for the pseudo-element that almost every button will need.
   You can just merge it into the style below if you are only going to have
   the play button. */
.button::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

/* Play button properties using font */
.play1.button::before {
  font-family: 'Webdings';
  font-size: 28px;
  content: '\25B6';
  top: -2px;
  left: 12px;
}

/* Play button properties using CSS shape */
.play2.button::before {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid white;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="play1 button" title="Play movie X">Play</a><br>
<a href="#" class="play2 button" title="Play movie X">Play</a>
```